# latest pushed commit not showing on local as well as remote repositor

Tags: git, git-commit

This is what I did to push my local changes to the remote
[commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwuB5.png)
[force push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t8BS.png)

But after doing this all all my local changes were gone and when I checked my remote repository, my latest commit wasn't there too. How can get my latest commit back?

I tried to checkout to staging pulled latest changes and rebase it into my branch. Also I tried `git reset --soft HEAD~1` but still it retrieve my second last commit not the latest one.

Comment: It's not clear what you did between the first and second screenshots, however, the first screenshot shows that you were detached when you made commit `f83b`. Presumably that's the commit you wish to get back, so maybe just checkout that commit or create a branch pointing to that commit. At least that will get you back to where you were...

Comment: I was missing just this command that I didn't checkout to detached commit. Thanks I got my code recovered